# From three integers, choose any two and replace one of them with the two numbers' mean. Show that we can obtain equal integers.

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

Let $a, b, c$ be three distinct positive integer numbers on a whiteboard. At each step, I choose two of them and I replace one of the two numbers with their arithmetic mean.

For example: I choose $a, b$ and I change $a$ with $\frac{a+b}{2}$. Then we will have $\frac{a+b}{2}, b, c$.

Show that after many steps we can obtain two equal numbers.

I tried a lot of combinations but I didn't succeed. Also I tried to make a program in C++ but I am not good enough.

Comment: Is $\frac{a+b}{2}$ allowed to be a non-integer ?

Comment: Two of them must have the same parity, average those two.  Argue that you can  always reducs the sum of the absolute differences that way.

Comment: Note:  not sure how to handle the case where you get down to $(a,a,b)$ where $a,b$ have opposite parity.  You need to argue that you can always avoid that.

Comment: Do you mean like $a=3,b=5,c=4$?

Comment: Oh, you only want two equal numbers.  Then my quick argument works fine.  You aren't afraid of $(a,a,b)$.

Comment: adding to @lulu 's comment. Choose the two with same parity, find their mean and replace the extreme number (either the largest or the smallest, but if the two numbers are the largest and smallest, replace the largest)

Comment: I've implemented the algorithm I discussed in prev. comment in python, and it worked for the 10 or so I've run the program with different inputs. But this comment box won't let me put the code with formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not $100$% sure about this one (please suggest any improvements), but here it goes:
Out of the three, at least two have the same parity by the [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). If all three have the same parity, choose $a$ and $b$. Call the two chosen numbers $x$ and $y$, where $x>y$. The mean is ${x+y}\over2$, which is an integer since they both have the same parity. Again, by the Pigeonhole Principle, at least one of $x$ and $y$ must be an extremum (that is to say, either a maximum or minimum). Replace that with ${x+y}\over2$. (If one is maximum and the other minimum, $y$). Since $x$ and $y$ have the same parity (and they are not equal, otherwise we are done), we have $x-y\ge 2$. 
Suppose we chose $x$, then the original triplet was $x,y,z$ in decreasing order (since we chose $x$, it is an extremum, and $x>y$ so it's a max. Since we didn't choose $y$, it isn't a minimum) for some $z$. The new triplet is ${x+y\over2},y,z$.
$${x+y\over2}<{x+x\over2} = x$$ since $x>y$. The new triplet still consists of integers, and $x - {x+y\over2} \ge 1$, so the bounds (that is max$(a,b,c)-$min$(a,b,c)$ have decreased by at least $1$. A similar argument works if we choose $y$ (Original - $p,q,y$ - since we don't know whether or not $x$ is the largest, new $p,q,{x+y\over2}$, $y<{x+y\over2}$). 
At every step, the bounds decrease by at least $1$ (either due to a decrease in maximum or an increase in minimum). Thus there must come a stage the values are 'squeezed', and either $a=b,b=c$ or $a=c$.

Here is a python code that implements the above algorithm (can someone make the syntax highlighting appear?):

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
g = 0
m = 0
ma = 0
mb = 0
mc = 0
x = 0
if a == b or b == c or a == c:
    print("Condition already satisfied")
else:
    print(str(a)+", "+str(b)+", "+str(c))
while a!=b and b!=c and c!=a:
    g = max(a,b,c)
    m = min(a,b,c)
    ma = a%2
    mb = b%2
    mc = c%2
    if mb == ma:
        x = (a+b)/2
        if a == m or b == m:
            if a == m:
                a = x
            if b == m:
                b = x
        else:
            if a == g:
                a = x
            if b == g:
                b = x
    elif ma == mc:
        x = (c+a)/2
        if c == m or a == m:
            if c == m:
                c = x
            if a == m:
                a = x
        else:
            if c == g:
                c = x
            if a == g:
                a = x
    elif mb == mc:
        x = (c+b)/2
        if c == m or b == m:
            if c == m:
                c = x
            if b == m:
                b = x
        else:
            if c == g:
                c = x
            if b == g:
                b = x
    print(str(a)+", "+str(b)+", "+str(c))
```

Maybe someone can implement this logic in C++ since I don't know that.